# Leetcode EASY Longest Common Prefix Explanation

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding the solution to this [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/)

The javascript solution is:

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    'use strict';
    if (strs === undefined || strs.length === 0) { return ''; }

    return strs.reduce((prev, next) => {
        let i = 0;
        while (prev[i] && next[i] && prev[i] === next[i]) i++;
        return prev.slice(0, i);
    });
};
```

Why does the while loop repeat `prev[i]` twice instead of once such as `while (prev[i] && next[i] === next[i])`?

It would be helpful if someone could explain each iteration of `i` for both inputs of Example 1 and 2 in the link.

Comment: **Why does the while loop repeat prev[i] twice** It only check once `prev[i]` and once `next[i]`

Comment: technically this code is wrong too because reduce is missing the accumulator argument. with the use strict statement, the function should throw an error!

Comment: How would you check if they're both defined and equal to each other?

Comment: The checks are 1. Does prev[i] exist 2. Does next[i] exist 3. Is prev[i] equal to next [i] ... if you want to be pedantic, you probably only need to check if prev[i] or next[i] exists, not both, since you only get into trouble if both of them don’t exist given the equality check.

Comment: This code really should be written as `while (i < prev.length && i < next.length && prev[i] == next[i])`. (Also the `next` variable actually should be named `cur`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = ["flower","flow","flight"];
```

With that input the comparison will be first between `flower` and `flow`, which have 4 characters in common so `i` will be equal to 4.

Inside of the while loop you iterate over all the characters of both, and you check three things:

- That the current character of `previous` exists
- That the current character of `next` exists
- That the current character of `previous` equals the current character of `next`

This is because the two words you are comparing can have different lengths.

On the second pass you compare `flow` and `flight`. Here you have to understand that **`flow` at this point is not the second word in the array**, `flow` is the result of the previous `splice(0, 4)` which is the common letters between `flower` and `flow`.

You are reducing the string you want to return by keeping only the common part of every two words. So in the second iteration of the reduction `i` is equal to 2 and you return `fl`.

```js
var example1 = ["flower", "flow", "flight"];

var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    'use strict';
    if (strs === undefined || strs.length === 0) { return ''; }

    return strs.reduce((prev, next) => {
        // 1st pass: prev="flower", next="flow"
        // 2nd pass: prev="flow", next="flight"
        console.log('prev=' + prev + ', next=' + next);
        
        let i = 0;
        // This while loop will iterate over each letter of both prev and next
        while (prev[i] && // prev[i] is truthy. It exists, it's not null or undefined
               next[i] && // next[i] is truthy. Same as before.
               prev[i] === next[i]){ // prev[i] and next[i] are the same character
          i++;
        }
        
        console.log('i = ' + i);
        
        // Since you incremented 'i' while both characters are equal
        // the common part is between index '0' and index 'i'
        return prev.slice(0, i);
    });
};

var result1 = longestCommonPrefix(example1);
console.log('Result 1: ' + result1);
```

If you execute the snippet I think you will understand much better how it works.

Here is the documentation on [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).